# Select2 Error on unselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 with a `multiple` `select` element to create an simpler user interface for adding many items to the select. Everything functions correctly - I can create the selector, add items, and remove items, however, when looking at my Javascript console log I am receiving two different errors when unselecting items.

1. > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
2. > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null

And from what I have found, the errors are a result of these lines:

```
$('#eleId').on("select2:unselect", function(){
    $('#eleId').select2();
});
```

I have removed some code to try to pinpoint the errors, but normally this code block would update some attributes of the element, set within the `select2({...})` call. The first error is given the first time removing an element after the the selection panel of options is opened and closed, so if the user clicks the selector, adds an item, then removes that item the first error is fired. The second error occurs when elements are removed not immediately following an opening and closing of the selection panel, so if the user were to add three items, removing the first would give the first error, removing the second and third would produce the second error for each item removed.

If I remove the `select2()` call within the function the errors go away, but the errors seem to be triggered by the `unselect` itself, since I have added a log statement to the end of the function and that will print before the error prints.

Working Copy:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select multiple id='eleId'>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#eleId').select2();
        });
        $('#eleId').on("select2:unselect", function(){
            $('#eleId').select2();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is your `("select2:unselect")` but can't promise anything, try creating a working snippet of the problem, then we have a better chance of helping you

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I have added code for repeating my exact error

Comment: Yanman do you want to clear it totally on removing 1 or ? because your question is a bit unclear about what specifically you want. but try with `$('#eleId').select2('val', 'All');`

Comment: So elsewhere in my actual code I am comparing the lengths of two selects and if their sum is 10, I set their `maximumSelectionLength` to their current length so the user cannot add more items to either. On an unselect I set `maximumSelectionLength` back to 10 to allow more items to be added. I removed this since the error was producible without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found this error is caused by select2 not loading the select element in time after the unselect event, so it could not immediately find the properties listed. To combat this I needed to wrap the `.select2()` call in a `setTimeout()` as such:

```
$('#eleId').on("select2:unselect", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#eleId').select2();
    });
});
```

This gives select2 just enough time to load the element before trying to access this properties. Though this solves the errors, it will produce a flickering effect with the selection panel when removing selections. To fix this I modify how the `opening` event is handled during this time:

```
$('#eleId').on("select2:unselect", function(){
    $(this).on('select2:opening', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#eleId').select2();
    });
    $(this).on('select2:unselect', function() {
        var sel = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            sel.off('select2:opening');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it helped me. Thanks a lot. Timeout helped to handle the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using the following worked for me and the errors disappeared:

```
$('.class').on('select2:select', function (e) {...});
```